# Como criar uma coluna calculada que incrementa um X % ao seu valor olhando pra linha anterior?

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-html, powerbi, business-intelligence

Possuo o seguinte cenário em meu Power BI:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso criar uma coluna calculada chamada "Meta", onde o primeiro valor será os "31297" e a partir disto, ele incrementará um valor de 4% sobre o último valor, exemplo:

```
linha 1 10
linha 2 15     (10+50%)
linha 3 22,5   (15+50%)
linha 4 33,75  (22,5+50%)
```

o resultado esperado é este:

```
linha 1 31.297 (valor_GMV)
linha 2 32.549 (Linha acima + 4%)
linha 3 33.851 (Linha acima + 4%)
linha 4 35.205 ....
linha 5 36.613 .....
etc..
```

Já revirei o google e não consegui uma solução que atende-se meu problema, o mais próximo foi usando o "EARLIER", porém não bombou*

Algum bom Samaritano pode me ajudar?

**apliquei o código abaixo:**

```
CumulativeSumValue =  
var indice = DIM_FORECAST[index] 
var valor_calc = DIM_FORECAST[VALOR_GMV] 
VAR taxa = DIM_FORECAST[TAXA_CRESCIMENTO_SEMANAL] 
return  
if(indice >1,     
CALCULATE(            
(sum(DIM_FORECAST[VALOR_GMV]) * 0.04) + 
sum(DIM_FORECAST[VALOR_GMV]),             
FILTER ( DIM_FORECAST, DIM_FORECAST[data_realizado] <= min( 
DIM_FORECAST[data_realizado]))) ,DIM_FORECAST[VALOR_GMV])
```

para primeira e segunda linha deu certo, porém depois apenas repetiu a segunda:

```
31297 32548,88 32548,88 32548,88
```

Comment: Explique " não bombou " ...

Comment: Olá @Motta apliquei o código abaixo:
`CumulativeSumValue = 
var indice = DIM_FORECAST[index]
var valor_calc = DIM_FORECAST[VALOR_GMV]
VAR taxa = DIM_FORECAST[TAXA_CRESCIMENTO_SEMANAL]
return 
if(indice >1,
    CALCULATE(
           (sum(DIM_FORECAST[VALOR_GMV])*0.04)+sum(DIM_FORECAST[VALOR_GMV]),
            FILTER ( DIM_FORECAST, DIM_FORECAST[data_realizado] <= min( DIM_FORECAST[data_realizado] ) ) 
    ) ,DIM_FORECAST[VALOR_GMV])`

para primeira e segunda linha deu certo, porém depois apenas repetiu a segunda:
31297
32548,88
32548,88
32548,88

Comment: Inseri o comentário no post